# How to keep usb device system file permission e.g. /dev/disk2 in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, file-permissions, automount

Beside using Disk Arbitrator, it can stop the device from auto mount, I would like to change the permission of a specific USB device for future use. 
For example, my diskXXX is may be change from disk1 or disk2 but I would like the device permission from rw-r----- to rw-rw---- 
Is there any doc online that I can understand the device creation process and user space automount model.